# My scrollbar doesn't go on the right side of browser?

Tags: html, css

I'm rather new to CSS/HTML. For a project of school I had to make a non-responsive 1140px website. I decided that I wanted the 1140px to have a white background color (in the middle of the browser) on both sides I wanted it to have a dark grey color.

So I put a dark grey color to my html and a white color to my body with a width of 1140px. I had to put a "overflow: hidden" on the html or else the white background color of the body doesn't show. But the problem is that because of that my scrollbar isn't on the far right side of my browser because of this hidden overflow, instead it goes on the right of my body.

Screenshot of my problem:

[image]

```
 html {
    background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #000000;
}
```

Is there a way to move my scrollbar to the right and ignore the overflow hidden property? Or another way to have the same background result?

Comment: Can you make a snippet or a jsfiddle or something that demonstrates the issue? There must be something else going on than what you're telling us here, because if I make [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/8m6w3876/1/) with your info, it simply shows the scrollbar at the right edge of the window.

Comment: You should generally try and avoid styling the html tag too much. In many cases the HTML tag is *not* seen as separate block element by browsers. Clearly here, you need to remove the overflow declaration for the HTML tag and find a better way to configure what you want... just the body, then a div for your content.

Comment: Indeed you're right Mr Lister, there was something else the problem so I looked through whole my CSS there was this code:

html,
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

I deleted that and it worked fine. Didn't occure to me that something else could be the problem thanks!

In the future I will try it another way, new to this but I will remember every, thank you too Scott!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `overflow:hidden` on your html and make your body width 100% and then make its background color transparent. This will give  you a full dark grey page (as the HTMl already has greay bckground). Now add a div inside the body and set its background color to white. Also make your div to be placed in the center by giving some margin left and margin right, Put all your content into this div. Thats it, Now you will have the scroll bar on the far right of the browser. Here is a snippet that might help you

```css
html{
  background-color:grey;
}

body{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-color:transparent;  
}

.appContainer{
   margin: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
   background-color:white;  
   height:2000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="appContainer">
 
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I will do it this way next time, I didn't know the correct way to do it :)

Comment: @SarahVanDenBerghe if this solution helped you resolve your issue, then please mark it as answer, As it might be useful for future audience